# How to show a continuous cannot differ a characteristic function by measure $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How to show that there is no continuous function on $\mathbb R$ such that it differs from $\chi_{[0,1]}$, the characteristic function of $[0,1]$, by a measure (Lebesgue measure) of $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $f$ be such function. For any $\delta > 0$, $(-\delta, 0)$ must contain an element $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$. Similarly, $(0, \delta)$ must contain an element $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be such a function. Since continuity is local, we may say that $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. Let

$$U = \{x \in (0,1): f(x) \neq \chi_{(0,1)}.\}$$

Then $U$ has measure zero because $f$ is assumed to be equal to $\chi_{[0,1]}$ almost everywhere. Then $U$ is open in $(0,1)$ because $f$ and $\chi_{(0,1)}$ are continuous functions on $(0,1)$. Since $(0,1)$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$, it follows $U$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$. But now no open set in $\Bbb{R}$ has measure zero which is a contradiction.